# How to get Month Name from datetime column in Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, datetime

I have a `DateTime` column in my table.

In Linq to SQL query, I only need Month part of that field

How to write the Linq query for that?

Answer (score 6):

Well, there are three options I can immediately think of:

- Pull the whole `DateTime` back, and then extract the month and format it client-side
- Use `DateTime.Month` to pull just the month back from the database, then format it client-side
- Try to get the formatting (conversion to text) to work on the database

Personally I would *not* try the third option - it feels to me like it's very unlikely to work, at least without a lot of effort.

I suspect I'd *actually* just pull the `DateTime` back, and do *everything* client-side. It's very easy to do that, and it's bound to work. I expect `DateTime.Month` will *probably* work, but you're not going to be saving *very* much network bandwidth, and you'll be getting the server to do work which is probably just as easy for the client to do.

Note that if you still want the results as a query, you can use `AsEnumerable` to force the remainder of the query to be done client-side. For example:

```
var query = db.Customers
              .Where(c => c.OrderCount > 500) // Or whatever query you want
              .Select(c => new { c.Name, c.FirstOrder })
              .AsEnumerable() // Do the rest of the query on the client
              .Select(c => new { c.Name, c.Month = c.FirstOrder.ToString("MMM") });
```

EDIT: As noted in comments, it makes sense to use `DateTime.Month` on the server side if it will actually affect the *results*, e.g.

```
var query = db.Customers.Where(c => c.FirstOrder.Month == 1)
                        ...
```

... but in those cases I'd expect it to be the numeric value which is important, not the *name* of the month.

Comment: The second option is good if u want to filter by month, but in the select the first option is fine to go for +1

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
string monthName = dataContext.GetTable<TableName>()
                              .FirstOrDefault(t => t.DateTimeColumn)
                              .ToString("MMM");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your table to `Enumerable` type by using `ToList()`, because you can't use `ToString()` on query type.

```
var result = from sales in SalesOrderHeaders.ToList()
    select new {
        Sales_Order_ID = sales.SalesOrderID,
        Territory_ID = sales.TerritoryID,
        Month = sales.OrderDate.ToString("MMMM"),
        Year = sales.OrderDate.Year
};
result.Dump();
```